# Problem creating a pop-up alert before app requests location permission in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-permissions

how to make a popup/alert in react native before the permission ask?

my code:

```
 const askPermission = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Permission");
      if (!askPermission){
        Alert.alert(
          "reason why..."
  
          [
            {
              text: "accept",
              onPress: () => {try {
                 AsyncStorage.setItem("Permission", 'true');
                this.requestLocationPermission()
              } catch (error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong", error);
              }}
            },
           
            // { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
          ]
        );
        
      }
..
  async  requestLocationPermission(){
 try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'location',
          'message': '....'
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can use the location")
        // alert("You can use the location");
      } else {
        console.log("location permission denied")
        // alert("Location permission denied");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }
```

I want to give a pop up before app location asking for permission.
but when I do that the permission is goes above/behind the alert.
so I even tried to do the alert only once with asyncstorage and still the alert goes behind the permission ask.

google-play dont let me publish if I dont give a pop up.

sorry for my english I hope I described it well

Comment: is this even possible for react native???

Comment: But isn't it enough to show the native popup triggered by the requestPermissions?

Comment: not for google:( maybe because Im using background location aswell. 
they send me:(screen shot of their answer): https://ibb.co/xfD0zw8

Answer (score 0):

bandage solution I made for now, it seem to work:
I created a navigation stack, put the permission flag in asyncstorage as I did before.
make an alert or would do some other modal/better UI.
if accepted or found in storage then navigate to the map screen.

if theres any better solution, would like to know